# Displaying unusual characters as button text in SWIXML

Tags: java, swing, unicode, swixml

I have the following SWIXML code:

```
  <panel id="contentPanel">
    <button text="∂"/>
    <button text="∆"/>
    <button text="∏"/>
    <button text="∑"/>
  </panel>
```

Notice the mathematical symbols that are used for text.  The symbols render fine in my Java IDE.  However, when I run the code, the symbols are not displayed correctly in the Swing component.  They each look like two characters, the first being an 'a' with diacritical marks and the second being some random character.

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you mean they render fine in the IDE's _editor_, or do you mean they render fine in your application when _run_ from the IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can use unicode char def e.g.
`text="\u2211"` for Sum

Answer (score 4):

The IDE's default encoding is probably UTF-8, while your platform is something else. Try examining the default encoding in both environments:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```