# Java card reader garbled

Tags: java, swing, io, keyboard, credit-card

I have a cheap magnetic card reader that acts like a keyboard.  I connect it and swipe a card, and it types all the card data into the computer.  But for some reason, it doesn't work in Java.  It does work in everything non-Java I have tried.

What is on the card (actually swiped card in SO editor):

`;00548757802?`

When using Java:

```
;0◘)P87┼7\02?
_005487578D♥
;005487G802?
_005*J657802{
♣00548I5♣802?
;≥T548757♠╢·?
≥T54875I↑:?
```

As you can see, it's different every time.  However, the reader sends a newline after the data, which Java does appear to recognize.

My code for reading input:

```
// Bound to a JTextField
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.print(e.getKeyChar());
}
```

The JTextField also shows the text garbled.

What is wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  My cheap $15 card reader was set to use alt-codes for data input, not plain keystrokes.  I was able to reprogram it with a utility I found online to emulate a normal keyboard instead of typing alt codes for every character.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've added a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to a [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), which uses [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) specific to each platform. Instead, use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read `System.in`; the `readLine()` method should be able to detect the line ending.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

To avoid blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), do the I/O in the background of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), `publish()` results as they become available, and update the `JTextField` in your implementation of `process()`.

Comment: Without any code, just the textbox, it still messes up.  The problem also crops up in Ubuntu with just about any application, Java or otherwise.

Comment: You might check the `file.encoding` system property.

Comment: All Java programs do this, not just mine.

Comment: I'm not surprised; the JVM uses a default [encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5573505/230513).